# Print number of matches of substring in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to print the number of matched sub string in an ansible variable.  In the following example, I am trying to print `2` as `abc` is present two times in the variable `vara`. and print `3`  as `abc` is present three times when checked for variable `varb`.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    vara: 'abc1\nabcdef'
    varb: 'def abc and abcd and abc'


  tasks:
   - debug: var=vara|regex_search('abc')
   - name: "Run this task when its condition in true"
     shell: echo abc in vara
     when:  (vara|regex_search('abc')) == 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) states you have to use the `regex_findall` filter in combination with the `length` function. `regex_findall` returns all occurrences of `regex` in a list. The `length` filter returns the number of elements in a list.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    vara: 'abc1\nabcdef'
    varb: 'def abc and abcd and abc'
  tasks:
   - debug: var=vara|regex_findall('abc')|length
   - debug: var=varb|regex_findall('abc')|length
   - name: "Run this task when its condition in true"
     debug: msg='abc in vara'
     when:  (vara|regex_findall('abc')|length) == 2
   - name: "Run this task when its condition in true"
     debug: msg='abc in varb'
     when:  (varb|regex_findall('abc')|length) == 2
```

outputs

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vara|regex_findall('abc')|length": "2"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "varb|regex_findall('abc')|length": "3"
}

TASK [Run this task when its condition in true] ********************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "abc in vara"
}

TASK [Run this task when its condition in true] ********************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: I am getting `"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{var1|regex_findall('mystring')|length}}): expected string or buffer"
`

Comment: @monk var1 must be a string. You can check type with type_debug - `{{ var1 | type_debug }}`